# Is it possible to use the web-push library for node-js in a deno supabase edge function?

Tags: node.js, supabase, deno, web-push

I tried to use/import the web-push library (https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push) for node-js in a deno supabase edge function and it does not work.

1. Is it possible to use the mentioned library in this case?
2. If not, why is it not possible?
3. If yes, how can I make it work?

My code

```
import * as webPush from "https://dev.jspm.io/web-push"

 
Deno.serve(async (req) => {

        const vapidKeys = {
            publicKey: '<The public Key',
            privateKey: '<The private Key>',
        }

        const webpush = webPush;

        webpush.setGCMAPIKey('<The GCM API Key>'); // TODO: I think this line times out 
        webpush.setVapidDetails(
            'mailto:example@yourdomain.org',
            vapidKeys.publicKey,
            vapidKeys.privateKey
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are compatibility issues with the crypto libraries. I built the same app in Deno and Node and Deno crashes when processing the private key with the error:

```
error: Uncaught TypeError: Invalid PEM label
    at SignImpl.sign (ext:deno_node/internal/crypto/sig.ts:36:33)
    at sign (file:///Users/aekidna/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/jwa/2.0.0/index.js:152:45)
    at Object.sign (file:///Users/aekidna/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/jwa/2.0.0/index.js:200:27)
    at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (file:///Users/aekidna/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/jws/4.0.0/lib/sign-stream.js:32:24)
    at Object.getVapidHeaders (file:///Users/aekidna/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/deno-web-push/3.5.0/src/vapid-helper.js:217:19)
    at Object.WebPushLib.generateRequestDetails (file:///Users/aekidna/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/deno-web-push/3.5.0/src/web-push-lib.js:253:40)
    at Object.WebPushLib.sendNotification (file:///Users/aekidna/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/deno-web-push/3.5.0/src/web-push-lib.js:310:29)
```

I tried to import web-push using esm with `target=deno` but that causes another error related to the implementation of `crypto.ECDH` (unimplemented)

I'm surprised nobody's on this.

Comment: It's been discussed here https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/18972